# MVC Razor View not found if filename contains a dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have problems accessing a route, if it contains a dot. For reproducing, create a default MVC4 WebApi application. Take the default route...

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

write the controller as follows...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(string id)
   {
      if (id == null)
      {
         return View();
      }
      else
      {
         return PartialView(id);
      }
   }
}
```

and create two files "test.cshtml" and "test.menu.cshtml" next to the existing "index.cshtml".

Opening /home/index/test works as expected. It brings back the contents of "test.cshtml".

However, opening /home/index/test.menu brings back a 404 error.

Why does this happen? And how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 error that you are seeing is from IIS.  The module for MVC routing is never getting control.

Adding the following option to the `modules` section of the `<system.webServer>` section in `web.config` will make sure that the MVC routing gets attempted and should fix your problem:

`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`

in my web.config there was no existing `modules` section so I added the following line to the `<system.webServer>` section:

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

And now it works for me.

Comment: Thank you. This works. However, after reading about this setting, maybe performance issues might arise.